# Sub asp.net MVC project in a MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc project with the follow structure:

- my-site

  - admin-folder (this folder will contain the mvc project of admin)

    - controllers
    - models
    - views
    - scripts
    - config file
  - controllers (this is controller of public site)
  - models (this is model of public site)
  - views (of public site)
  - config file

I want to completely separate the back-end and front-end, with "http://my-site.com/" it will go to the front-end, with "http://my-site.com/admin" it will point to back-end. Anyone can help me config it? Thanks!

Comment: You could probably achieve this with "Areas" and/or "custom routing". Searching for those terms (with MVC) should provide good results.

Comment: Create an Area called "Admin" and you're set, you just need one project